# Class and inheritance

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand the inheritance system in Ruby. This is my code :

```
class Man
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name = "Foo")
    @name = name
  end
end

class User < Man
  attr_accessor :mail

  def initialize(mail = "bar")
    super
    @mail = mail
  end
end
```

And this is my test :

```
man = Man.new
man
=> #<Man:0x007fb68da4a768 @name="Foo">

user = User.new
user
=> #<User:0x007fb68da442c8 @name="bar", @mail="bar">
```

I don't understand why user's @name isn't "Foo" ! Normaly, it should because it's the default argument in the man's initialize method, no ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` (without an argument list) calls the same method in the superclass with the same arguments that were passed in. If you want to *explicitly* pass *no* arguments, you *must* use an empty argument list: `super()`.

Remember: `super` is not a method call, it's a keyword and keywords don't have to follow the normal method call evaluation rules. This is one of those differences. For a method call, `foo` and `foo()` are equivalent, they both pass no arguments. For `super`, there *is* a difference: `super()` passes no arguments, `super` *forwards* the arguments.

Now, here's an additional twist: actually, you *don't* pass any arguments to `initialize`, so how are they getting passed on … or do you? Well, it turns out, for the purposes of calling `super`, default arguments to optional parameters are treated as if they had been passed explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer! I thought it was a method like the other!

Answer (score 2):

`super` without arguments is a shortcut for passing the same arguments that were passed into the currently executing method. In your example, "bar" was passed implicitly to the super-class (that's why you are getting "bar" for them both).

An optional solution to avoid confusion:

```
class User < Man
  attr_accessor :mail

  def initialize(name = "foo", mail = "bar")
    super(name)
    @mail = mail
  end
end
```

Comment: Why you define two parrameters? you can call `super()` with no parram and you get default value from Parent class

Comment: @LukasBaliak, that's correct. But what if we wanted to define them both other than default values? This variation has an advantage.

Comment: that's correct, but he whant to understand why the name was define as mail. Ofc you can use this to "redefine" name var.
After `super()` you can use `user.name = "new name"`

Comment: @LukasBaliak, thanks for your feedback. I'll clarify that the code intended to advice an optional solution. The reason is explained in the previous sentence: super with no parameters takes the current function parameters, no matter how they are being called. As for last your suggestion - I think it is more like a workaround you better not use a lot. If you have a parameter - pass it. Do not let the default to occur and then override it.

Answer (score 0):

You call the User class with one parrameter, and inside initialize you call parent class with same parrameter bcs. you use `super` like this.

If you call `super()` you dont send parrameters bcs you call Parent initial method with no parrameters.

like this

```
class Man
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name = "Foo")
    @name = name
  end
end

class User < Man
  attr_accessor :mail

  def initialize(mail = "bar")
    super()
    @mail = mail
  end
end

Man.new
# => #<Man:0x52a7e380 @name="Foo">
User.new
# => #<User:0x11777eb0 @mail="bar", @name="Foo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and it will work for you:

```
class Man
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name = "Foo")
    @name = name
  end
end

class User < Man
  attr_accessor :mail

  def initialize(mail = "bar")
    super()
    @mail = mail
  end
end

man = Man.new
puts man.name  #> Foo
user = User.new
puts user.name  #> Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

super without arguments, calls the initializer of the superclass with the same arguments it was called itself. You can see that, because name has the same value as mail.

What you want to do is:

```
def initialize(mail = "bar")
  super()
  @mail = mail
end
```

By using the brackets, the default of the other initializer is used, as  you have intended.